# GridViewRow in Method from other Method called from button within GridView creating wrong values C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a method

```
 protected void SignOffBT_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = e.CommandArgument.ToInt();
        string serviceFormId = Request.QueryString["sfid"];
        string serviceFormCompletedId = Request.QueryString["sfcid"];
        string currentEmployee = Fn.CurrentEmployeeName();
        Label NotificationLB = (Label) FormGV.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("NotificationLB");
        if (serviceFormId == maintenanceActionCompletionFormID.ToString())
        {
            if (QuestionLabelLB.Text.ToLower().Contains("approve"))
            {
                ApprovedByEmployeeIDHF.Value = Fn.CurrentEmployee().ToString();
                SignOffBT.Visible = false;
                NotificationLB.Text = "Approved by " + Fn.CurrentEmployeeName();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceFormCompletedId))
                {
                    redirect = false;
                    SaveForm();
                    .........
```

The SignOffBT_Command is called from within a GridView from the following button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SignOffBT" Text="Sign Off" Visible="False"  CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' OnCommand="SignOffBT_Command"/>
```

The SignOffBT_Command calls the SaveForm() method.

In the SaveForm() method I have a foreach as follows

```
foreach (GridViewRow tr in FormGV.Rows)
{
```

The problem is that the code is not behaving as expected. The if conditional statements are passing that should fail, etc. I can see this behaviour in the value of variables at breakpoints.
Does anybody have any ideas? Is it because the original method from the button is contained in the GridView and the method called by that method wants to iterate over the whole GridView? Is this allowed?

Comment: Have you debugged the variables used within if whether they have values or not?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that the variables behave so that the SaveForm() method is called correctly. The weird behaviour is in the SaveForm() method in each iteration of the `GridView` in the FormGV.Rows

Comment: @EmptyWaterHoles It is indeed unusual if `Label NotificationLB = (Label) FormGV.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("NotificationLB");` gives expected results but iterating over the rows later does not. I am not sure this will work, but could you try to pass a reference of `FormGV.Rows` in `SaveForm();`, meaning `SaveForm(FormGV.Rows)` and update the method appropriately with the parameter.

Comment: I tried have tried that now and am getting the same errors

Comment: Share your full code.